# Lost control over my MariaDB installation

Tags: macos, mariadb, macports

I installed MariaDB on my mac with Macports but lost control over it, mysteriously. I can list the processes and I can login using a user with no privileges. But if I try to stop the database using the usual macports command (`sudo port unload mariadb-10.1-server`) I get the following error:

```
/opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.mariadb-10.1-server/org.macports.mariadb-10.1-server.plist: Could not find specified service
```

I've tried installing and uninstalling but this doesn't change. How can I do a fresh install of MariaDB on my mac?

Comment: `SELECT user, host, Select_priv, Insert_priv FROM mysql.user;`  This may give a starting point for cleaning up the privileges.

Comment: @RickJames No permission to query that table.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've deleted the directory where this installation was and reinstalled from Macports. That solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you inadvertently installed another version of mariadb-server?  You can check with:

```
port echo active |grep mariadb-
```

It is also possible that the server was started without using launchd and so can't be stopped with the command you were using.  You can check with:

```
sudo launchctl list |grep macports
```

'org.macports.mariadb-10.1-server' will be in the list if it is running under launchd.

Comment: Only one MariaDB server, isn't listed under launchctl. I only install packages via Macports and reinstalling did not fix the issue.

Comment: If it is not running under launcd, then it should not survive a reboot.  Do that and then start the db server with the 'port load ...' command.

Comment: I can confirm that it has survived a reboot.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.  The normal way to start a daemon like this after a reboot is via launchd.  If it is running, what does 'ps -xa |grep mysql' report?

Comment: `⟩ ps -xa |grep mysql
   81 ??         0:18.40 /usr/local/mariadb/server/bin/mariadbd --user=_mysql --basedir=/usr/local/mariadb/server --log-basename=mariadb --plugin-dir=/usr/local/mariadb/server/lib/plugin`

Comment: MacPorts installs to /opt/local by default so it looks like the running version of the database came from Homebrew or a .dmg installer.